# Error in Python usig pygame (AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'right')

Tags: python, pygame

I have been making a game using python, following the instructions of a book I bought (2019 edition), but after about 300-400 lines of code, my game ran into an error which for the life of me I cannot fix. The error is the following: "AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'right'". And the code with the error is the following:

```
def prep_score(self):

    """Turn the score into a rendered image."""
    score_str = str(self.stats.score)
    self.score_image= self.font.render(score_str, True,
        self.text_color, self.settings.bg_color)

    # Display the score at the top right of the screen.
    self.score_rect = self.score_image.get_rect()
    self.score_rect.right = self.screen_rect.right - 20  <----- error line
    self.score_rect.top = 20
```

I have compared it to the book for about an hour, and when I run just this module (scoreboard.py) it doesn't appear to have any errors, but then I run the game module (alien_invasion.py) and I get that error in the terminal. The author also has a resource pack with the exact code from this chapter, and when I run that code it works just fine, but my version doesn't, which makes no sense because the module "scoreboard.py" is the same but the "alien_invasion.py" module is different, but because it has parts of the code which appear later in the book, I can't know what is the code that make a difference.

Here´s the alien_invasion.py code that envolves this:

```
from scoreboard import Scoreboard
(...)

def __init__(self):

    pygame.init()
    self.settings = Settings()

    self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((0, 0), pygame.FULLSCREEN)
    self.settings.screen_width = self.screen.get_rect().width
    self.settings.screen_height = self.screen.get_rect().height
    pygame.display.set_caption("Alien Invasion")

    # Create an instance to store game statistics.
    self.stats = GameStats(self)

    self.ship = Ship(self)
    self.bullets = pygame.sprite.Group()
    self.aliens = pygame.sprite.Group()

    self._create_fleet()

    # Make the Play button.
    self.play_button = Button(self, "Play")
    self.sb = Scoreboard(self)

(...)

def _update_screen(self):


    # Redraw the screen during each pass through the loop.
    self.screen.fill(self.settings.bg_color)
    self.ship.blitme()
    for bullet in self.bullets.sprites():
        bullet.draw_bullet()
    self.aliens.draw(self.screen)

    # Draw the score information.
    self.sb.show_score()    

    # Draw the play button if the game is inactive.
    if not self.stats.game_active:
        self.play_button.draw_button()

    # Make the most recently drawn screen visible
    pygame.display.flip()
```

There is more code in between but this is the only one that actually involves this.

Thank you and if you can please try to give me some tips about his, I am really desperate (first time in a forum).

Comment: Where do you define `screen_rect`? Also, what book are you using? I think I've read the same book once

Comment: Please provide the full traceback. A [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would also help.

Comment: This should be the referenced code: https://github.com/mihailgaberov/alien-invasion-python/blob/master/scoreboard.py

Comment: This may be a typo. The OP should have missed the parenthesis in `self.screen_rect = self.screen.get_rect()` in the `__init__` function.

Comment: That sounds plausible. @Nuno_Coelho, missing the `()` after a function call creates a function object and does not call it

Comment: First of all thank so much for answering. How do I share the whole code of the project?

Comment: Oh thanks! That was totally it!

Comment: This was super helpful thank you, the problem was the missing parentheses.

Comment: P.S. : The book is called "Python Crash Course 2nd edition" by Eric Matthes